# Regular expression for deleting a column using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So my HTML table looks like this:

```
<table class="mon_list" id="mon_list">
    <tr class='list'>
        <th class="list" align="center"><b>Klasse(n)</b></th>
        <th class="list" align="center">Stunde</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">Fach</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">Raum</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">Vertretungs-Text</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">Vertr-Text-2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='list odd'>
        <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #FFFFFF"><b>6.1</b></td>
        <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">1 - 2</td>
        <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">Ku</td>
        <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
            <s>312</s>006</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

and I need to delete the last column. I cannot find a regular expression for that. I need to delete the 6th element in each row.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: No, I'm not. Should I be using jQuery? I'm not really into that..

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery, is just that some people prefer using jQuery because it simplify some operations. Anyway I think that the answer by Felipe may solve your problem.

Comment: Regular expressions for manipulating HTML are a bad idea. Stick to DOM manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a column, you could loop through each row and remove the cell at the specific position (in this case the last one)

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    row.removeChild(row.cells[row.cells.length - 1]);
}
```

Let me know if that works

Answer (score 1):

This can be read as an XY problem, that is "how do I do X using Y",
perhaps the question could be rephrased as, "how do I do X",
I think in this case Y is the "regular expression".

I also think your code could use better formatting, would you mind editing the question?

in JavaScript you can remove rows by using the DOM removeChild() API passing the ID of the column row like so:

```
var rows = document.getElementById("tableObj").querySelector("tr");
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
    var cols = rows[i].querySelector("td");
    for(var r=0;r<cols.length;r++){
        if(r == 3){ //i.e. delete fourth column
            rows[i].removeChild(cols[r]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An XY problem is when someone *mistakenly* thinks they have to do X when instead they should be trying to do Y. It's not "how do I do X using Y".

Comment: The HTML file is an exported file from another program (timetable program), therefore I didn't format it.

Comment: Looks like I misread the question you want to delete columns, instead of rows. you can pass your code through a simple javascript DOM parser which iterates over the nodes and creates a new table with just the columns you want, as for the XY thing, I think "regex" is not reliable in this context and doing the DOM program would yield better results.

Comment: I think I have thought about regexpressions too much today, sorry for that. Thanks for the advice anyway, but Michaels solution works perfectly for me.